# Пытаюсь нарисовать arccos, но не выходит

Tags: python, matplotlib

Пытаюсь нарисовать arccos, но не выходит  :(

Пытаюсь наривать вот так :

```
Y = [ i*0.01 for i in range(0,314)]   # массив с шагом 0.01 от нуля до числа ПИ
X = [mt.acos(Y[i]) for i in range (len(Y))]   # Подставляем в аркосинус 
ax = plt.gca()
# plot X - axis    
ax.axhline(y=0, color='k')
# plot Y - axis    
ax.axvline(x=0, color='k')
lt.ylim(-max(Y), max(Y))
plt.xlim(-max(X), max(X))
plt.plot(X,Y)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Выдаёт ошибку :

> X = [mt.acos(F[i]) for i in range (len(F))]
>       ValueError: math domain error

Я не могу понять почему ??

Comment: попробуй через numpy.arccos(y).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данной строке:

```
X = [mt.acos(Y[i]) for i in range (len(Y))]
```

вы пытаетесь посчитать арккосинус значения большего единицы. Область значений косинуса: `[-1, 1]` и, соответсвенно, область определения `arccos`: `[-1, 1]`. Все что выходит за этот диапазон по оси `X` для `arccos` не имеет смысла.

---

```
In [28]: import numpy as np

In [29]: x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)

In [30]: plt.plot(x, np.arccos(x))
Out[30]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0xe51fa90>]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]